# How do i route external API URL + credentials into my localhost URL using visual studio WebAPI project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

I currently only have the External API credentials as a result access token in Postman but cannot implement the URL and credentials into c# code using ASP .NET Web API which comes with sample code in the controller but currently have nothing inside because I don't know how to redirect the external url:https://api.elliemae.com/oauth2/v1/token 
towards my localhost URL

[postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcR0H.png)

Currently i only have created my model class assuming I will need it. 
Class Name: Credentials.cs

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace APICredential.Models
{
    public class Credentials
    {
        public string grant_type { get; set; } = "password";
        public string username { get; set; } = "admin@encompass:BE11200822";
        public string password { get; set; } = "Sh**********";
        public string client_id {get;set;} = "gpq4sdh";
        public string client_secret { get; set; } = "dcZ42Ps0lyU0XRgpDyg0yXxxXVm9@A5Z4ICK3NUN&DgzR7G2tCOW6VC#HVoZPBwU";
        public string scope { get; set; } = "lp";


    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using APICredential.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace APICredential.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost, Route("post")]
        public async Task<string> Post([FromBody]Credentials cred)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.elliemae.com/oauth2/");

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
                (HttpMethod.Post, "v1/token")
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cred), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                //for now, see what response gets you and adjust your code to return the object you need, if the api is returning a serialized json string.. then we can return a string here... like so

                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return result;
            }
        }


        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you're going to need to create a dto that has similar properties to the stuff you're sending to this api end point. and also a model to map the data that's being returned

```
public class Credentials
{
    public string grant_type { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string client_id {get;set;}
    public string client_secret { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
}
```

then you're going to instantiate it and start assigning the values before sending it off

this is going to go in your api controller method

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost, Route("values")]
    public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        Credentials cred = new Credentials()
        {
            grant_type = "password",
            username = "admin@encompass:BE11200822",
            password  = "Shmmarch18",
            client_id = "gpq4sdh",
            client_secret = "dcZ42Ps0lyU0XRgpDyg0yXxxXVm9@A5Z4ICK3NUN&DgzR7G2tCOW6VC#HVoZPBwU",
            scope = "lp"
        };

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.elliemae.com/oauth2/");

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
                (HttpMethod.Post, "v1/token")
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cred), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                //for now, see what response gets you and adjust your code to return the object you need, if the api is returning a serialized json string.. then we can return a string here... like so

               string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

               return result;
           }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

There's a chance you might have to serialize the object that's returning from the API call, if that's the case:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost, Route("values")]
    public string Post([FromBody]Credentials cred)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.elliemae.com/oauth2/");

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            (HttpMethod.Post, "v1/token")
            {
                Content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cred), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

           string result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response.Content);

           return result;
       }
    }
}
```

Nice work! Ok, let's test your API, let's pump your Get Method up and make it an easy one to work with to increase moral hehe

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet, Route("values")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "Nice! At least we got this one working, Fay... the Id value you entered is: " + id.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194564/discussion-on-answer-by-jphizzle-how-do-i-route-external-api-url-credentials-i).

Comment: John did you see what i sent you yesterday from gethub?